# Updating many item using same id in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I am saving values in two tables asset and asset_history.On creating asset i am saving values in asset table if any update i wantthat time it as to store in asset and asset_history on id bases . Now i want to get two tables value in edit page for getting asset_history i used sql query to get values in asset_history.all are working well and fine but it is coming  in array list values(all update list is showing in single row).when i updata values in edit page it should save and show in different rows in asset_history. for that i used for loop but it not getting values.

asset table  i have these fields :-

```
     id
      asset_title
      asset_description
      client_id
      comment
      status
etc...
```

In asset_history field:-

```
id
comment
update_on
update_by
status
```

If any update in asset field.The update list should save in both asset and asset_history.I have used a query to update(as shown below). But it is getting arraylist in asset_history table.

edit action

```
    def dataSource
def edit={
    def assetInstance = Asset.get(params.id)
        if (!assetInstance) { 

            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'asset.label', default: 'Asset'), params.id])}"
            redirect(action: "list")
        }
        else {  Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource) 
             def result = sql.rows("SELECT * from asset_history where id ='"+params.id+"' ")
            //def n=result

            /*  def arr = (String[])result
                        for(i in 0 .. result.size()-1)
                         {

            return [assetInstance: assetInstance,result:i]
                         }*/
                   return [assetInstance: assetInstance,result: result]
        }

    }
```

In edit.gsp

```
<tbody>

                        <tr>


                          <td>${result.id}</br></td>
                            <td>${result.comment}</br></td>

                            <td>${result.update_on}</br></td>
                           <td>${result.update_time}</br></td>
                               <td>${result.update_by}</br></td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
```

In asset_history table the values are getting in arraylist and showing updated list in  single row.But i want show it in separate row ,when i update each time.I used for-loop for this but it is not working.Please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: In order to get better answer, you may be interested in this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81648 . Try to write shorter questions and try harder to write good english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you can only return one value from a function in Groovy (and in all other languages I know anyway). So the first iteration in your for loop returns and the following iterations (where you expect to return more instances) are not executed.

You must return a list and use a `<g:each>` tag in your GSP file (which is the equivalent to a for loop in GSP):

```
def edit = {
  def assetInstance = Asset.get(params.id)
  if (!assetInstance) {
    flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'asset.label', default: 'Asset'), params.id])}"
    redirect(action: "list")
  }
  Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource) 
  def results = sql.rows("SELECT * from asset_history where id ='" + params.id + "' ")
  return [results: results]
}
```

And your GSP:

```
<tbody>
  <g:each var="result" in="${result}">
    <tr>
      <td>${result.id}</br></td>
      <td>${result.comment}</br></td>

      <td>${result.update_on}</br></td>
      <td>${result.update_time}</br></td>
      <td>${result.update_by}</br></td>
    </tr>
  </g:each>
</tbody>
```

As a bonus, here are a few tips that will make your application look better:

- Don't return values if you don't use them in your GSP, like `assertInstance` here
- Avoid using SQL and prefer relying on Grails built-in access methods (`findBy`) or Hibernate Criteria if your assert history are Grails domain objects. This will give you Grails objects backs instead of *raw* SQL rows
- Indent your code correctly for readability. Chances are that your IDE have a feature that can do that for you.